# How can I set the latex path for sweave in R?

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, sweave, pdflatex

I would like to know how I can set the pdflatex path in `R` to use `sweave`. Because I have 2 different MikTeX installations and one is working properly. Please take into account that I am using R (RStudio) in `Windows`. I found some suggestion however, for Linux or Unix users.

thanks in advance

Comment: Check this question on RStudio forum:https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200662347-Rstudio-not-finding-git-on-windows

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you have multiple installs of LaTeX (i.e. MikTeX) and you want to use a specific one of these, then you need to make sure that R finds the one you need first. This means that you have to add the location of your preferred version of pdfLaTeX at the front of your PATH system environment variable.

If you do not have administrator rights in Windows, then you can use R's environment file to change the PATH variable for R only. See `?Startup` in R for details on this process. Follow the following steps:

1. in R, check the output of `Sys.getenv("R_ENVIRON")`. This will return the full path to an existing environment file, but will be empty in most cases. If a file exists, skip to step 3 below.
2. if no path is returned in step 1, create a file *Renviron.site* in the folder *R_HOME/etc* where *R_HOME* is the path returned by `Sys.getenv("R_HOME")`.
3. add a line to the environment file as follows: `PATH=C:\\full\\path\\to\\the\\folder\\with\\pdflatex;"${PATH}"` (the quotations marks are important)
4. restart R and check `Sys.getenv("PATH")` and `Sys.which("pdflatex")` returns the correct paths.

If you do not have rights to create a *Renviron.site* file in *R_HOME\etc*, then you can also create a *.Renviron* file in *HOME* (`Sys.getenv("HOME")`).

Comment: This treatment helps me when I try to create the pdf manual for my R package. That is to run the code such as `R CMD check MyPackagePath` and `R CMD Rd2pdf  PackagePath`

Comment: You can also try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50082865/miktex-did-not-succeed-after-i-updated-r-to-version-3-5-0) if you're coming here after issues with MikTeX 2.9.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about step 2? I don't understand how to locate the R_HOME/etc ...