# Bookmarks not working with RMarkdown (pdf) and titlesec

Tags: formatting, latex, r-markdown

I was looking for a way to change heading format in RMarkdown (pdf) and found this code which works just fine.

```
---
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
  - \usepackage[tiny]{titlesec}
                  \titleformat*{\section}{\center\bfseries}{}
---
```

However, the heading are not correct in the bookmarks of the document, i.e., all sections ends up a level lower than the previous (regardless of their actual level).

Here is an example.

```
---
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
  - \usepackage[tiny]{titlesec}
                  \titleformat*{\section}{\center\bfseries}{}
---


# Level 1

# Level 1

## Level 2

### Level 3

# Level 1

## Level 2
```

And this is the resulting bookmarks.

[image]

Thank you,

Comment: Can't reproduce with up-to-date pandoc, rmarkdown and texlive 2021. Are your tools up-to-date? https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzSfk.png

Comment: Maybe check in another pdf viewer as well?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I have Rmarkdown 2.11, Pandoc 2.17.0.1. Updated every packages I had. I still have the problem. I've tried in adobe and it does not work either. Thank you!

Comment: can you show your latex .log file?

Comment: I am not sure how to share it? What is the best way?

Comment: If it is not too long, it should fit into the maximum character limit of your question. Else there is https://pastebin.com/ or github  etc

Comment: I can not seem to be able to keep the log files. I can with the tex files. It their a trick for that?

Comment: With `output: pdf_document: keep_tex: true`, the .log file should be left in your folder

Comment: I thought so, but it deletes it.

Comment: mmm, too bad. My best theory would be an outdated tex installation

Comment: I'm installing tex live and have an updated tinytex. Not sure what I could do. Thank you!

Comment: If I run the TEX files in Miktex, bookmarks are correct. I've tried on another computer and it produces the same error. Have you tried to run only in Rmarkdown @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz ?

Comment: Yes, the screenshot I showed you was produced from rmarkdown, via pandoc to the pdf. I've seen many questions in which rmarkdown/pandoc would pick up an old tex distribution instead of the one the users normally use. That's why I would love to see your log file

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I've managed to get the log file and to drop it on git hub. Here it is : https://github.com/quantmeth/MethQuantR/blob/main/test.log

Comment: You must fix the error `! LaTeX Error: File titlesec.sty not found.` otherwise latex can't correctly compile

Comment: if your files works in your miktex, maybe try to make rmakddown use miktex instead of texlive. Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/33670021/2777074 can help