# How can I configure the latex path for R sweave?

Tags: r, windows, latex, rstudio, pdflatex

I want to use latex in Rstudio, for this I installed some time ago the Miktex but I installed it in the D disk, so when running in Rstudio this did not catch it, then I uninstalled it and installed the tinytex(https://yihui.org/tinytex/) and it did not run with all the packages that I wanted to use. After a while I tried again and installed again the Miktex but now on disk C, but now I get the path error.

[Compile pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ciRU.png)

Recently I saw a publication ([How can I set the latex path for sweave in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33650869/how-can-i-set-the-latex-path-for-sweave-in-r#comment120535604_33670021))of solution of the error but I don't understand the steps very well since they ask me to create a Renviron.site in the R folder but it doesn't let me, besides I don't know what I should add to that file. If someone knows how to configure it or how to follow the steps of the publication it would help me a lot please.

[Miktex 2.9 vs Miktex 1.9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arotg.png)

Comment: I think you would be better off using `knitr` than using `Sweave`.  Working on Rnw files, `knitr` does everything that `Sweave` does with very similar syntax, but also adds a lot of flexibility and common sense.  `tinytex` is written by the author of `knitr`, so I'd just expect things to go more smoothly working with those two, especially as you seem to be using RStudio.